# AWS API Gateway returns a 403 with x-amzn-ErrorType:AccessDeniedException header

Tags: amazon-web-services

**The context**

I have a serverless web app built with AWS trio: API Gateway + Lambda + DynamoDB. 
The first page of the app send 2 http requests to get data and combine reponses to print the result.

```
            / APIGateway /projects      => Lambda (DynamoDB request)   \
web app => {                                                            } => display data
            \ APIGateway /organizations => Lambda (Github API request) /
```

**The problem**

Every goes fine the first time I ask for the page. But if I try to refresh this page, I get a `403` error on `/organizations` request. From there, if I wait ~3-5 minutes and I refresh the page again I correctly see all the data and my page is perfectly displayed. Sometimes, the `GET /organizations` fails, sometimes, it's the `GET /projects`.

Why I have to wait to be able to correctly refresh the page ? How can I fix it ?

**Additional informations**

When I have this `403` error, ...

- I get a `200 OK` response to the `OPTIONS /organizations` request
- I don't see the `GET /organizations` request at all in the cloudwatch log (the `OPTIONS` request is there, but not the `GET`)
- Response headers are:

  ```
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:60
  Content-Type:application/json
  Date:Mon, 12 Dec 2016 11:31:29 GMT
  Via:1.1 af2dd53407c5eae7ddf5c44e27a5dd1b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  X-Amz-Cf-Id:Kl1JS1ZCCJuGAmydXv3qDoq3E-rFZrlZbs8Bgvw8RSrb8xsjEyAJNQ==
  x-amzn-ErrorType:AccessDeniedException
  x-amzn-RequestId:8689b86c-c05e-11e6-b851-7ff70d9a3125
  X-Cache:Error from cloudfront
  ```

  (I dont know why I have `x-amzn-ErrorType:AccessDeniedException` and `X-Cache:Error from cloudfront`)
- I have a CORS error in my chrome console :

  ```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://********.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/organizations. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
  ```

  (... even if CORS is enabled and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is present in the `OPTIONS` response headers)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Sylvain, did you find the issue causing this? I'm running into this a bit as well.

Comment: In my case, it turned out that I was including the stage name with the custom domain. [As explained here,](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/m6d5l1/comment/hmamdgt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I had to make sure to remove it. (I'm not posting this as answer, as I'm unsure if this is your problem.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The origin of this issue was the custom authorizer which was generating a custom policy for a specific resource. As this policy was cached, when the second request arrives, it doesn't match with the one previously generated and returns an error.

#### Workaround: Disabling the cache

- open the AWS console on the API Gateway service,
- click on your API,
- select **Authorizers** in the left pane and select your custom authorizer

In the **Result TTL in seconds**, type **0** and click **Update**. Now, you have to deploy your API to publish your changes :

- click on the **Resources** menu in the left pane and in the **Actions** dropdown menu, click **Deploy API**
- select the stage and click **Deploy**

### Solution: Improve your policy

```
def generatePolicy(principalId, context):
  return {
    'principalId': principalId,
    'policyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Action': 'execute-api:Invoke',
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Resource': 'arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/prod/*'
        }]
    },
    'context': context
  }
```

You can be more precise in the **Resource** property with an array:

```
'Resource': [
  'arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/prod/GET/projects',
  'arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/prod/GET/user',
  ...
]
```

You can either Allow a superset of ressources and Deny specific ones.

> Have a look on @Jeremiah 's link : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225934&tstart=0

Comment: If you use the AWS lambda authorizers examples and tailor the policy to the resource, please remember that any variable caught in the method path will be part of the cached policy !
Any further call with a different value there will be rejected without mercy.